# center point of a text?

Tags: xna-4.0, spritebatch, text

i'm drawing a text using a spritefont and the draw.string function of the spritebatch object. in some point, i need to augment the size of the text, so i use a variable to scale it. all this is working fine, but i need to find the center of the text to use as origin to make the effect look like i want. how can i find that center point of a text? when i use textures its easy because i just take half the texture width and height, but with a spritefont, i dont have any idea of how to proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [SpriteFont.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritefont.measurestring.aspx).

```
Vector2 textSize = mySpriteFont.MeasureString("Hello World");
Vector2 center = textSize / 2;
```

The x component of `textSize` represents the width of the measured string while the y component represents the height.

Comment: great, that is the answer, it works perfectly. thanks!